# Getting email from LoggedIn user with Github

Tags: python, django, django-allauth

I have successfully setup Django with Django-allauth to register with Github but even if inside the scope on settings and asking for , it does not store the user's email address on the database.

Here is the settings block:

```
SOCIALACCOUNT_PROVIDERS = {
    'github': {
        'SCOPE': [
            'user',
            'emails',
            'repo',
            'read:org',
        ],
    }
}

ACCOUNT_EMAIL_REQUIRED = True
```

Is there any configuration left to do or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Please add more details. Do you get any error message? What is it?

Comment: I could log in sucessfully but it only stores the username on the database and not the emails

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the answer. Django-allauth provides the email by accessing the extra data.

`from allauth.socialaccount.models import SocialAccount`

`SocialAccount.objects.all()`

Answer (score 1):

add this line in settings.py and it will work fine

```
SOCIALACCOUNT_QUERY_EMAIL = True
```